# My multi-step form not getting validated

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap, validation, twitter-bootstrap-3

I am trying to validate my multi-step form using bootstrap validation method but facing a strange error

```
 Uncaught Error: One or more corresponding step titles are missing.
```

I googled it many times but didn't find solution that can sort out my issue.

Where is the mistake actually?

Script.js

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    function adjustIframeHeight() {
        var $body   = $('body'),
            $iframe = $body.data('iframe.fv');
        if ($iframe) {
            // Adjust the height of iframe
            $iframe.height($body.height());
        }
    }
    $("#profile_form").steps({
        headerTag: "h4",
        bodyTag: "fieldset",
        saveState: true,
        onStepChanged: function(e, currentIndex, priorIndex) {
                // You don't need to care about it
                // It is for the specific demo
                adjustIframeHeight();
            },
            // Triggered when clicking the Previous/Next buttons
            onStepChanging: function(e, currentIndex, newIndex) {
                var fv         = $('#profile_form').data('formValidation'), // FormValidation instance
                    // The current step container
                    $container = $('#profile_form').find('fieldset[data-step="' + currentIndex +'"]');

                // Validate the container
                fv.validateContainer($container);

                var isValidStep = fv.isValidContainer($container);
                if (isValidStep === false || isValidStep === null) {
                    // Do not jump to the next step
                    return false;
                }

                return true;
            },
            // Triggered when clicking the Finish button
            onFinishing: function(e, currentIndex) {
                var fv         = $('#profile_form').data('formValidation'),
                    $container = $('#profile_form').find('fieldset[data-step="' + currentIndex +'"]');

                // Validate the last step container
                fv.validateContainer($container);

                var isValidStep = fv.isValidContainer($container);
                if (isValidStep === false || isValidStep === null) {
                    return false;
                }

                return true;
            },
            onFinished: function(e, currentIndex) {
                // Uncomment the following line to submit the form using the defaultSubmit() method
                //$('#multiphase').formValidation('defaultSubmit');

                // For testing purpose
              //  $('#welcomeModal').modal("show");
            }
        }).formValidation({
        excluded: ':disabled',
        message: 'This value is not valid',
        container: 'tooltip',
        feedbackIcons: {
            valid: 'glyphicon glyphicon-ok',
            invalid: 'glyphicon glyphicon-remove',
            validating: 'glyphicon glyphicon-refresh'
        },
        fields: {..................}
......................
```

html

```
                        <form id="profile_form" role="form" action="" method="post" class="form-inline">

                            <fieldset data-step="0">
<h4>Introduction <span class="step">(Step 1 / 7)</span></h4>
<div class="form-group">
  <label for="first-name">First Name:</label><br>
  <input type="text" name="firstname" class="first-name form-control" id="first-name">
</div>
<div class="form-group">
  <label for="last-name">Last Name:</label><br>
  <input type="text" name="last-name" class="last-name form-control" id="last-name">
</div>
<div class="form-group">
  <label for="height">Height:</label><br>
  <input type="text" name="height" class="height form-control" id="height">
</div>
<div class="form-group">
  <label for="weight">Weight:</label><br>
  <input type="text" name="weight" class="weight form-control" id="weight">
</div>
<br>
<button type="button" class="btn btn-next">Next <i class="fa fa-angle-right"></i></button>
</fieldset>

<fieldset data-step="1">
<h4>Place and Date of Birth <span class="step">(Step 2 / 7)</span></h4>
<div class="form-group">
  <label for="birth-city">City:</label><br>
  <input type="text" name="birth-city" class="birth-city form-control" id="birth-city">
</div>
<div class="form-group">
  <label for="birth-state">State / Province:</label><br>
  <input type="text" name="birth-state" class="birth-state form-control" id="birth-state">
</div>
<div class="form-group">
  <label for="birth-country">Country:</label><br>
  <input type="text" name="birth-country" class="birth-country form-control" id="birth-country">
</div>
<div class="form-group">
  <label for="birth-date">Date (YYYY/MM/DD):</label><br>
  <input type="text" name="birth-date" class="birth-date form-control" id="birth-date">
</div>
<br>
<button type="button" class="btn btn-previous"><i class="fa fa-angle-left"></i> Previous</button>
<button type="button" class="btn btn-next">Next <i class="fa fa-angle-right"></i></button>
                            </fieldset>

                        </form
```

>

Comment: Your question has nothing to do with the jQuery Validate plugin.  Removed [tag:jquery-validate] tag.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to add title property to your state definition?

```
$("#profile_form").steps({
    headerTag: "h4",
    title: "profile details".
    bodyTag: "fieldset",
    saveState: true...
```

Comment: If you still have a problem - try to create a document on plnkr with all code so we can check it.